# trivial regarding isalpha() in while()

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

Don't mind the obscure number of headers I'm using. I'm just copying the snippit of code I'm having problems with, and included every header because it wont hurt.

I am making a simple check to see if user input for an intended integer is not a character. If the user inputs a character, they will be brought back to the beginning of the while loop until an integer is entered.

```
      while (edgeLength<4 || edgeLength>12)
    {
      //...
    }
```

This makes sure that a number between 4 and 12 is entered, and works as intended.

My question:

Why is it that when I enter any character, say 'x', the contents of the while loop loop infinitely?
I specify `isalpha(edgeLength)` as a condition to lookout for, but no luck.

```
#include <math.h>   // for exponents
#include <iostream> // for cout<< and cin>>
#include <stdlib.h> // for exit() and rand()
#include <ctype.h>  // for conversion to upper case and isalpha
#include <time.h>   // for seeding random generator
#include <iomanip>  // for formatting the board (setw)
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int edgeLength;
cout<<"Enter the size board you want, between 4 and 12: ";
  cin>>edgeLength;


  while (edgeLength<4 || edgeLength>12 || isalpha(edgeLength))
      {
      cout<<"Invalid size.   Choose a value between 4 and 12: ";
      cin>>edgeLength;
      }
      return 0;

}
```

current output:

```
Enter the size board you want, between 4 and 12: e
Invalid size.   Choose a value between 4 and 12:Invalid size.   Choose a value between 4 and 12:Invalid size.   Choose a value between 4 and 12:Invalid size.   Choose a value between 4 and 12:Invalid size.   Choose a value between 4 and 12:Invalid size.   Choose a value between 4 and 12:Invalid size.   Choose a value between 4 and 12:Invalid size.   Choose a value between 4 and 12:Invalid size.   Choose a value between 4 and 12:
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

desired output:

```
Enter the size board you want, between 4 and 12: e
Invalid size.   Choose a value between 4 and 12: 5
[process returns 0]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When cin expects an int, but the input cannot be converted to int, it fails and leaves the input data in the stream. So, if you loop, you keep reading the same data over and over again, failing each time to convert it to an int. Note that cin >> edgeLength returns false if the cast fails, so you could test this.

[This page](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/21595/) explains it all, along with a code snippet to handle the situation properly :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<limits>

using namespace std;
int main()
{

    cout << "Enter an int: ";
    int x = 0;
    while(!(cin >> x)){
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cout << "Invalid input.  Try again: ";
    }
    cout << "You entered: " << x << endl;       
}
```

Comment: I thought cin>> would handle input like scanf. This helped me, thank you!